# Getting syntax error in sql query using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the following error while using MySQL query.

> Error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'o.user_id='RNAYAK2009@GMAIL.COM' and (o.status='Successful' or o.status='Pending' at line 1

I am explaining my query below.

```
SELECT o.order_id,o.order_date,o.payment_amount,
       o.status,op.pro_data_id,pd.image,pd.pro_Id,pi.Product_name
FROM db_order AS o
LEFT JOIN db_order_products AS op ON o.order_id = op.order_id 
LEFT JOIN db_product_data AS pd ON op.pro_data_id=pd.pro_data_id 
LEFT JOIN db_product_info AS pi ON pd.pro_Id=pi.pro_Id 
WHERE o.user_id='RNAYAK2009@GMAIL.COM' 
    and (o.status='Successful' or o.status='Pending')
```

Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: change `pi.pro_IdWHERE` to `pi.pro_Id WHERE` and `pi.  Product_name` to `pi.Product_name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to repaste it, but it looks like two errors from what you pasted:

```
pi.  Product_name
```

and

```
pi.pro_IdWHERE
```

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong formatted, here we go:

```
SELECT
        o.order_id,
        o.order_date,
        o.payment_amount,
        o.status,
        op.pro_data_id,
        pd.image,
        pd.pro_Id,
        pi.Product_name
    FROM
        db_order AS o
    LEFT JOIN db_order_products AS op ON o.order_id = op.order_id
    LEFT JOIN db_product_data AS pd ON op.pro_data_id = pd.pro_data_id
    LEFT JOIN db_product_info AS pi ON pd.pro_Id = pi.pro_Id 
    WHERE o.user_id = 'RNAYAK2009@GMAIL.COM'
    AND (
        o.status = 'Successful'
        OR o.status = 'Pending'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it as below :

```
    SELECT 
        o.order_id,
        o.order_date,
        o.payment_amount,
        o.status,
        op.pro_data_id,
        pd.image,
        pd.pro_Id,
        pi.Product_name
    FROM
        db_order AS o
            LEFT JOIN
        db_order_products AS op ON o.order_id = op.order_id
            LEFT JOIN
        db_product_data AS pd ON op.pro_data_id = pd.pro_data_id
            LEFT JOIN
        db_product_info AS pi ON pd.pro_Id = pi.pro_Id
    WHERE
        o.user_id = 'RNAYAK2009@GMAIL.COM'
            AND (o.status = 'Successful'
            OR o.status = 'Pending')
```